# Not able to enter input in a textbox (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to access a textbox to enter some values in it, but my code doesn't find the element I'm searching for (I've tried it via xpath, id, and class).

Since I have a WebDriverWait condition, a TimeoutException occurs. I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong, since this method worked for other pages I tried it in!

My code (and webpage):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.bancosantander.es/es/particulares/prestamos/prestamos-personales/simulador')

# Find textbox
amountBox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="amount"]')))

# Set amount to 10000  
amountBox.clear()
amountBox.send_keys('10000')
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Python\.spyder-py3\scrapingTest.py", line 14, in <module>
amountBox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="amount"]')))

File "C:\Users\Python\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

TimeoutException
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An iframe is present on the page, so you need to first switch to that iframe and then operate on the element.
You can do it like:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.bancosantander.es/es/particulares/prestamos/prestamos-personales/simulador')

#Switch to the iframe
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe'))

# Find textbox
amountBox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="amount"]')))

# Set amount to 10000  
amountBox.clear()
amountBox.send_keys('10000')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's inside `iframe`, you need switch it first.

Please utilize `.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it` method:

```
driver.get('https://www.bancosantander.es/es/particulares/prestamos/prestamos-personales/simulador')

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'iframe[src]')))

# Find textbox
amountBox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="amount"]')))

# Set amount to 10000  
amountBox.clear()
amountBox.send_keys('10000')
```